# How to put parameterize value in CSV file including new line

Tags: csv, jmeter

How should I parameterize the Message body value as it is in the format mentioned (with new line)in CSV file as one value in JMeter tool

```
 "QU SKYTEAM  
.TPEFMCI 170219   
FFR/8  
297-50347905CANJFK/T10K20MC0.12/GENERAL  
/XPS   
CZ123/31DEC/CANJFK/NN  
REF/TPEFMCI   
CUS//  
/CANCSNCARGO  
/GUANGZHOU  
SRI/PRD-EQUATION"
```

[The image attached is the script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSAqz.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can work it around using [JMeter Functions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

- Scenario 1: you have file with multiple lines, i.e:

  ```
  foo
  bar
  ```

  In this case you can use [__FileToString()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) function like: `${__FileToString(/path/to/the/file/with/the/payload,,)}`
- Scenario 2: you have file with the data in single line having [line breaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) like:

  ```
  foo\r\nbar
  ```

  And the relevant JMeter Variable holding this value is `${baz}`

  In this case you can use [__javaScript()](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function which will convert line breaks characters into new lines like: `${__javaScript("${baz}",)}`

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) to learn more about above and other JMeter functions

Comment: Thanks for the help. But I want to provide the whole text that is present under Message Body as mentioned in the image as one value in the CSV file. While I am putting the whole value in one cell of CSV file,its taking only first line of the text.

Comment: It depends on how many "whole values" you have. If it is only one - go for __FileToString(), if there are many of them - convert line breaks into `\r\n` and use __javaScript()

Comment: we have 100 no. of data to be parameterized like the mentioned data in " " as one value in CSV file. But when I am putting the value in CSV file in one cell ...it is taking only  "QU SKYTEAM" but not total value.Please help